# Why can't I successfully bind a DataGridviewColumnCollection to a ComboBox.DataSource and specify a Display/ValueMember?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

While trying to bind a combo up so that the user can select a column name from the dropdown and I retrieve the column index from the SelectedValue, I noted that the combo appears to ignore the given DisplayMember and ValueMember and instead uses the ToString()

Repro:

- Place a new DataGridView and ComboBox on a form, leaving their default names
- Put the following code over the top of the user Form1:

```
    

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("A");
    dt.Columns.Add("B");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(DataGridViewColumn.Name);
    comboBox1.ValueMember = nameof(DataGridViewColumn.Index);
    comboBox1.DataSource = dataGridView1.Columns;
}
```

- Run the app. You'll see two entries in the combo, but not `Name` "A" and "B" - instead it looks to use the `ToString()`:

[image of form - please embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcKWZ.png)

If the order of items is swapped:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dataGridView1.Columns;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(DataGridViewColumn.Name);
comboBox1.ValueMember = nameof(DataGridViewColumn.Index);
```

C# complains the DisplayMember cannot be set. I'm even more confused because:

- After setting the `comboBox1.DataSource = dataGridView1.Columns;` the Display/ValueMembers are both `""`
- After setting the `comboBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(DataGridViewColumn.Name);` the DisplayMember is still `""`
  [image of debugger stopped after setting displaymember - please embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah9Ul.png)
- After setting the `comboBox1.ValueMember = nameof(DataGridViewColumn.Index);` the **DisplayMember** is set to `"Index"` and an exception is thrown
  [image of debugger stopped after setting valuemember - please embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m39kb.png)

Tweaking the collection type doesn't produce any different result either:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList();
```

---

The problem appears to be in relation to the DataGridViewColumn class attempting to bind. If the column collection is projected to an anoymous type with the same prop names, it works without a problem:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Select(c => new { c.Name, c.ColumnIndex }).ToList();
```

I'm curious why DataGridViewColumn, apparently a class with public named props like any other, doesn't work directly in this binding scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because those properties are not browsable.

It not something special with `DataGridViewColumn` class and the behavior is the same even for a custom created class. Those properties (Name and Index) are marked as `[Browsable(false)]` and when setting up databinding, the [CurrencyManager.GetItemProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.getitemproperties?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) just returns browsable properties.

If you start tracing the code from [ValueMember](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,3700b49cdaae76be), you will end up in some [internal methods](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListBindingHelper.cs,3cd0b6db8926c195) which check for browsable attributes.

The best workaround is the one that you also mentioned, shaping the result to a custom type:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .Select(c => new { c.Name, c.ColumnIndex }).ToList();
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Index";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! Any comment on why the DisplayMember property ended up (so the debugger claims) being set to what I'd actually set ValueMember to?

Comment: I guess the answer is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,349) and later [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,741).